# Java Script, returning print values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return print statements. Every code I put seems to be wrong. Not an expert in Java Script.

Its a frog hopping program

If the frog cannot reach it's destination, I want it to return a phrase saying "Frog cannot reach end"
If the frog can reach the end, I'd like it to display the number of hops

```
Obj = {0:1,1:3,2:6,3:4,4:5,5:0,6:2,7:-1};
D=3;
X=0;
Y=7;

function frogHop(obj, D,X,Y)
 {
   var arr=[];
   for(var key in obj){
     arr[key]=obj[key];

   }


   var now=X;
   var hops=0;
   var hopped=[];
   flag=1;
   while (Math.abs(now-Y)>D)
   {
     hopped.push(now);
     now=arr[now];
     if (hopped.indexOf(now)!=-1)
     {
       flag=0;
       break;
     }
     hops+=1;
   }
   if (flag==1)
   {
     if (now==Y)
       return hops;
     else
       return hops+1;
   }

   return -1;
   print("Cannot reach destination")

}

alert(frogHop(Obj,D, X,Y));
```

Comment: instead of `print` use return to send the message back from the method. Since you are using `alert` that should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try returning the answer as a string

```
Obj = {0:1,1:3,2:6,3:4,4:5,5:0,6:2,7:-1};
D=3;
X=0;
Y=7;

function frogHop(obj, D,X,Y)
 {
   var arr=[];
   for(var key in obj){
     arr[key]=obj[key];

   }


   var now=X;
   var hops=0;
   var hopped=[];
   flag=1;
   while (Math.abs(now-Y)>D)
   {
     hopped.push(now);
     now=arr[now];
     if (hopped.indexOf(now)!=-1)
     {
       flag=0;
       break;
     }
     hops+=1;
   }
   if (flag==1)
   {
     if (now==Y)
       return "The amount of hops was " + hops;
     else
       hops++;
       return "The amount of hops was " + hops;
   }

   return "Cannot reach destination";

}

alert(frogHop(Obj,D, X,Y));
```